# refresh a JLabel

Tags: java, jtable

This is as the title says, I need your help to refresh the contents of a JLabel.

I explain my worries.
I have a first JFarm or I have a calendar (a DatePicker) which allows me to select a date and a button.
When I click on the button it opens a new window and in this famous window I have my JLabel or I would like to see my date.

In this last window I wrote:

```
System.out.println(datePicker.getDate());
labelDate.setText(datePicker.getDate());
```

When I first open my window everything works fine, but if I close it, I change the date in my DatePicker and reopen the window by clicking on my button the date does not change !!!
It always remains on the first date sent.

Yet my:

```
System.out.println(datePicker.getDate());
```

Returns the correct date correctly each time.

Do you have an idea ?
Thank you all.

Comment: Can you add the code for opening the window?

Comment: It could be a lot of things, i.e. you are wrongly thinking the jLabel is the same and instead you are initializing a new one. Can you show a little more of your code to let we understand better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again me,

I found my error !
In my WindowAbsence :

```
private static JPanel panelWindow = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

The panel it was in static...
i hope will serve for someone !

Answer (score 0):

I post my full code but it's very long and not very clean... sorry.

the main window :

```
public class App extends JFrame{

    private JPanel contentPane;
    static final int rowMultiplier = 4;
    private DatePicker datePicker;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    App frame = new App();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public App()  throws SQLException{
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        this.setTitle("Absences Management");
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);


// =================== PanelTitle ===================================       
        JPanel panelTitle = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panelTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel labelTitle = new JLabel("Absence Management");
        panelTitle.add(labelTitle);

// ================== PanelMenu =====================================
        JPanel panelMenu = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panelMenu, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panelMenu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMenu, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        // Border and name for the panel
        panelMenu.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" Menu "));


        // create buttons and set the actions for the menu
        JButton buttonAddClass = new JButton(new ActionButtonClassManagement(this,"Class management"));
        JButton buttonQuit = new JButton(new ActionButtonQuit(this,"     Quit     "));


        // add different components in the Panel Menu
        panelMenu.add(buttonAddClass);
        panelMenu.add(buttonQuit);



// ================= PanelCalendar ==================================       

        JPanel panelCalendar = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panelCalendar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelCalendar.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        // black border for the panel
        panelCalendar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" Calendar "));

        JLabel labelCalendar = new JLabel("CALENDAR :");        
        panelCalendar.add(labelCalendar);

        // ===== create the calendar
        // settings
        DatePickerSettings dateSettings = new DatePickerSettings();
        dateSettings.setVisibleClearButton(false);
        // set the current date by default
        dateSettings.setAllowEmptyDates(false);

        datePicker = new DatePicker(dateSettings);


        // create a icon
        URL dateImageURL = FullDemo.class.getResource("/img/calendar20x20.png");
        Image calendarImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(dateImageURL);
        ImageIcon calendarIcon = new ImageIcon(calendarImage);

        // create button and set the icon
        JButton datePickerButton = datePicker.getComponentToggleCalendarButton();
        datePickerButton.setText("");
        datePickerButton.setIcon(calendarIcon);

        // add the calendar to the PanelCalendar
        panelCalendar.add(datePicker);
        // create a button Show absences
        JButton buttonAbsence = new JButton(new ActionButtonAbsences(this,"Absences", datePicker));

        //add the button to the panelCalendar
        panelCalendar.add(buttonAbsence);

    }

}
```

The class for my button Absence :

```
public class ActionButtonAbsences extends AbstractAction{

    private App windowAbsence;
    private DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    private String dateString = new String();

    public ActionButtonAbsences(App app, String textButton, DatePicker datePicker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(textButton);  
        this.datePicker = datePicker;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        dateString = datePicker.getText();
        WindowAbsence fen = new WindowAbsence(windowAbsence, datePicker, dateString);
    }
}
```

And the window that opens when I press the button Absence :

```
public class WindowAbsence extends JDialog implements ActionListener{


    private static JPanel panelWindow = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel panelTitle = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelWindowLeft = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelWindowRight = new JPanel(); 

    private JComboBox comboBoxClass;
    private JComboBox comboBoxStudent;
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private JLabel labelDate = new JLabel();
    private String dateString = new String();

    private ModelTable modelTableAbsence = new ModelTable();
    private JTable tableAbsence = new JTable(modelTableAbsence);


    public WindowAbsence(Frame frame, DatePicker datePicker, String date){
        //super call the constructor of the main window
        // the first argument is the mother window
        // the second argument disable this window
        super(frame,true);

        labelDate.setText(datePicker.getText());

        this.dateString = date;


        // add BorderLayout in this Window
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // name of the window
        this.setTitle("Absences");
        // size of the window
        this.setSize(700, 600);
        // effect for the red cross
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.datePicker = datePicker;

        // =================== Data bases connection ============================               
        /**
        * download mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.tar.gz
        * https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=470332
        * Clic droit sur le dossier du projet
        * Clic right on the folder of the project
        * Build Path
        * Add external Archive
        */

        DataBase database = new DataBase();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AbsenceManagement";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        try {
            database.connectionDataBase(url, user, pass, driver);


    // ================== PANEL TITLE ==================================
            //JLabel labelDate = new JLabel();
            panelTitle.add(labelDate);
            //labelDate.setText(datePicker.getText());
            date = datePicker.getText();

            System.out.println("date: "+date);
            labelDate.setText(date);


            panelWindow.add(panelTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // ================ PANEL LEFT =====================================
        panelWindowLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" Absences "));
            // =========== panelComboBoxLabelClass ======================
        JPanel panelLabelComboBoxClass = new JPanel();
        panelLabelComboBoxClass.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelLabelComboBoxClass, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        JLabel labelComboBoxClass = new JLabel("Class :");
        comboBoxClass = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxClass.addItem("");
        panelLabelComboBoxClass.add(labelComboBoxClass);
        panelLabelComboBoxClass.add(comboBoxClass);     


        Statement statementClass = DataBase.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultClass = statementClass.executeQuery("SELECT class FROM Class");

        //receive the MetaData
        ResultSetMetaData resultMetaClass = (ResultSetMetaData) resultClass.getMetaData();

        // add the data in the row
        while(resultClass.next()){
            comboBoxClass.addItem(resultClass.getObject(1));
        }

        comboBoxClass.addActionListener(this);


        resultClass.close();
        statementClass.close();

            // =========== panelComboBoxLabelStudent ======================
        JPanel panelLabelComboBoxStudent = new JPanel();
        panelLabelComboBoxStudent.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelLabelComboBoxStudent, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        JLabel labelComboBoxStudent = new JLabel("Student :");
        comboBoxStudent = new JComboBox();
        panelLabelComboBoxStudent.add(labelComboBoxStudent);
        panelLabelComboBoxStudent.add(comboBoxStudent); 

        // ========== panelComboBoxHour ===============================
        int rowMultiplier = 4;
        int row = rowMultiplier;

        TimePickerSettings timeSettings = new TimePickerSettings();
        timeSettings.setDisplayToggleTimeMenuButton(true);
        timeSettings.setDisplaySpinnerButtons(false);



        JPanel panelComboBoxHour = new JPanel();
        panelComboBoxHour.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelComboBoxHour, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));


        JLabel labelComboBoxFrom = new JLabel("From :");
        panelComboBoxHour.add(labelComboBoxFrom);

        TimePicker timePickerFrom = new TimePicker(timeSettings);
        timePickerFrom = new TimePicker();
        panelComboBoxHour.add(timePickerFrom, getConstraints(1, (row * rowMultiplier), 1));
        //panelComboBoxHour.addLabel(panelComboBoxHour, 1, (row++ * rowMultiplier), "Time 1, Default Settings:");


        JLabel labelComboBoxTo = new JLabel("To :");
        panelComboBoxHour.add(labelComboBoxTo);

        TimePicker timePickerTo = new TimePicker();
        timePickerTo = new TimePicker();
        panelComboBoxHour.add(timePickerTo, getConstraints(1, (row * rowMultiplier), 1));

        // ========== panel button add absence ==============
        JPanel panelButtonAddAbsence = new JPanel();
        panelButtonAddAbsence.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelButtonAddAbsence, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        JButton buttonAddAbsence = new JButton("Add Absence");
        panelButtonAddAbsence.add(buttonAddAbsence);
        // ========================================

        panelWindowLeft.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelWindowLeft, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panelWindowLeft.add(panelLabelComboBoxClass);
        panelWindowLeft.add(panelLabelComboBoxStudent);
        panelWindowLeft.add(panelComboBoxHour);
        panelWindowLeft.add(panelButtonAddAbsence);

        panelWindow.add(panelWindowLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
        // ====================== PANEL RIGHT ================================


        panelWindowRight.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" Absences "));


        //=================== TABLE =======================================

        Statement statementAbsence = DataBase.connection.createStatement();
        // requet SQL
        ResultSet resultAbsence;
        ResultSetMetaData resultMetaAbsence;        

        modelTableAbsence.addColumn("Student");
        modelTableAbsence.addColumn("Date");
        modelTableAbsence.addColumn("To");
        modelTableAbsence.addColumn("From");

        // requete SQL 
        resultAbsence = statementAbsence.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Absence WHERE `dateAbsence`='"+datePicker.getDate().toString()+"'");

        //receive the MetaData
        resultMetaAbsence = (ResultSetMetaData) resultAbsence.getMetaData();
        modelTableAbsence.fireTableDataChanged();

        if(!resultAbsence.next()){
            System.out.println("null");
        }else{
            // add the data in the row
            do{
                  modelTableAbsence.addRow(new Object[]{
                          resultAbsence.getObject(2).toString(),
                          resultAbsence.getObject(3).toString(),
                          resultAbsence.getObject(4).toString(),
                          resultAbsence.getObject(5).toString()
                  });
            }while(resultAbsence.next());
            // close the statementClass
            statementAbsence.close();
            resultAbsence.close();


            // =========  replace id student by firstName and lastName
            Statement statementNameStudent = DataBase.connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultNameStudent = null;

            int nbRow = modelTableAbsence.getRowCount();
            for(int i = 0; i < nbRow; i++){

                resultNameStudent = statementNameStudent.executeQuery("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM Student WHERE `id`='"+modelTableAbsence.getValueAt((i), 0)+"'");
                // add the data in the row
                  while(resultNameStudent.next()){
                      modelTableAbsence.setValueAt(
                              (resultNameStudent.getObject(1)+" "+resultNameStudent.getObject(2)),i,0);
                  }
            }
            statementNameStudent.close();
            resultNameStudent.close();

        }

        // =================================================================
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tableAbsence);

        panelWindowRight.add(scrollPane);
        panelWindow.add(panelWindowRight, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setContentPane(panelWindow);
        this.setVisible(true);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static GridBagConstraints getConstraints(int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth) {
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gc.gridx = gridx;
        gc.gridy = gridy;
        gc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        return gc;
}
    // model table for table schedule
    public class ModelTableSchedule extends DefaultTableModel {
        ModelTableSchedule(Object[][] dataStudent, String[] columnNamesStudent) {
            super(dataStudent, columnNamesStudent);
        }
        // the function return always false, the table is never editable
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        modelTableAbsence.fireTableDataChanged();


        // =================== Data bases connection ============================               
        /**
        * download mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.tar.gz
        * https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=470332
        * Clic droit sur le dossier du projet
        * Clic right on the folder of the project
        * Build Path
        * Add external Archive
        */

        DataBase database = new DataBase();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AbsenceManagement";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

            try {
                database.connectionDataBase(url, user, pass, driver);

                // add value in ComboBox
                Statement statementStudent;
                comboBoxStudent.removeAllItems();
                statementStudent = DataBase.connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultStudent = statementStudent.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `Student` WHERE `class` LIKE '"+comboBoxClass.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");
                //receive the MetaData
                ResultSetMetaData resultMetaStudent = (ResultSetMetaData) resultStudent.getMetaData();      
                // add the data in the row
                while(resultStudent.next()){
                    comboBoxStudent.addItem((resultStudent.getObject(2)+" "+resultStudent.getObject(3)));
                }
                comboBoxStudent.revalidate();
                resultStudent.close();
                statementStudent.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
    }   
}
```

Thank you for your help.